# Python Найти уникальное число с помощью списка из 100 нулей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте, учусь Питону. Столкнулся с задачей:

> У вас есть список от 0 до 99, в нем повторяются числа, кроме одного.
> Используйте список из ста нулей, чтоб найти уникальное число.

Нужно именно так, остальные способы я сделал через `xor` и перебором, нужно именно через список с нулями.

```
list2 = [0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 98, 3, 1, 98, 7, 16, 16, 4, 0, 42, 54, 54, 6, 6] 
list3 = [0] * 100 
for i in range(len(list3)):
    z = 0
    for j in range(len(list2)): 
        if list3[i] == list2[j]: 
            i += 1 
            j += 1 
            z += 1
        else: 
            list3[i] != list2[j] `
            print(list2[j], z) 
    break
```

В каком направлении думать? И если кто переделает код, укажите пожалуйста комментариями, что откуда выполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in list2:
    list3[i] += 1

result = list3.index(1)    
print(f"Уникальное число: {result}")
```

---

*Вывод для вашего списка `list2`:*

> Уникальное число: 42

---

*Объяснение:*

Присвоим каждому целому числу из диапазона 0-99 число на соответствующей позиции в списке `list3` (пока речь *не идет о списке `list2`*). Здесь таблица:

```
числа:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ...  97  98  99 
        ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓        ↓   ↓   ↓
list3:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  ...   0   0   0             ← сначала самые нули
```

Теперь начинаем проходить списком `list2` - в нем находятся только числа из *первой строки нашей таблицы:*

```
for i in list2:
```

Для каждого числа в этом списке повысим соответствующее число в последней строке нашей таблицы:

```
    list3[i] += 1
```

Значит, когда находим (например) число 4 первый раз:

```
числа:  0  1  2  3 |4| 5  6  ...  97  98  99 
        ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓ |↓| ↓  ↓        ↓   ↓   ↓
list3:  ?  ?  ?  ? |1| ?  ?  ...   0   0   0 
                    ↑
```

и когда затем его встретим второй раз:

```
числа:  0  1  2  3 |4| 5  6  ...  97  98  99 
        ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓ |↓| ↓  ↓        ↓   ↓   ↓
list3:  ?  ?  ?  ? |2| ?  ?  ...   ?   ?   ? 
                    ↑
```

В результате мы в списке `list3` получим

- 0 (нули) - для чисел из диапазона 0-99, с которыми мы в списке `list2` *не встретились*
- **1 (единицу)** - только одну, для **уникального** числа
- 2 - для чисел, которые мы встретили дважды
- 3 - для чисел, которые мы встретили трижды
- ... и т.д.

Значит, достаточно только *обнаружить позицию (индекс) этой единицы:*

```
result = list3.index(1)
```

Comment: Объяснение отличное, лаконичная реализация, но я не знаю пока, как работают словари {}

Comment: спасибо вам большое, догнал как без словаря

Comment: @MarianD написали бы просто `print('Уникальное число:', result)` без мучений для новичков)

Comment: В [f-строке](https://python-scripts.com/f-strings) `f"Уникальное число: {result}"` фигурные скобки **не означают словарь**, а часть, вместо которой Питон **подставит результат выражения в этих скобках,** в вашем случае `42`.

Comment: @Павел, вы прав, это один из подходов, которым я тоже пользуюсь. Но иногда я пытаюсь новичка чему-то научить. Спасибо за ваш комментарий, он будет для многих полезным.

Answer (score 2):

Для каждого числа x из первого списка выполните

```
list3[x] += 1
```

Потом проверьте, какие элементы равны единице